# jQuery Help Adding and Deleting Elements in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble figuring out how to delete a single entry (the last item) in a text area. Any help/suggestions is much appreciated. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WeAb4/1/) example.

Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() { 
    var addName = jQuery('input.addName'),
            addLanId = jQuery('input.addLanId'),
            addPerId = jQuery('input.addPersonId'),
            textArea = jQuery('textarea.addPersonInfo');

    addPerId.keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\$]/g,'');            
    });

    jQuery('.btn-add').on('click', function() {
        var addNameValue = addName.val(),
            addLanIdValue = addLanId.val(),
            addPerIdValue = addPerId.val();

        if (addNameValue == '' || addLanIdValue == '' || addPerIdValue == ''){
            return false;
        }

         var elFormat = addNameValue + " (LAN ID: " + addLanIdValue + ") (Person ID: " + addPerIdValue + ")\n",
            addEl = jQuery(textArea).append(elFormat);
            addName.val('');
            addLanId.val('');
            addPerId.val('');   


    }); 

    jQuery('.btn-delete').on('click', function() {              
        jQuery('.addPersonInfo:last-child').remove();

    });     


});
```

Comment: What exactly is an "entry" in a textarea?

Comment: Can you jsfiddle this please?  The JS alone isn't helpful, and I suspect if you edit with a slab of HTML it might not be all that helpful either.  so if you can put the example online in jsfiddle that would be much appreciated.

Comment: A user fills out a couple of text inputs (name and user id) and it gets appended to a text box.

Comment: Why a `textarea` (there's *no such element* as a 'textbox' (this is a long-standing peeve of mine))? Why not put the entries from the inputs into, for example, a list? Please show the minimal ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) html and JavaScript (is that really the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem?).

Comment: The info needs to be passed to a $_POST variable.

Comment: you should be using forms to pass form data to $_POST

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have text in your text area and you need to remove the last line of it.  You could grab the contents of the textarea, split it using the javascript split method, remove the last line and join them together:

```
<textarea id="t">
line 1
line 2
</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">

  lines = $("#t").val().split("\n");

  // remove the last line
  lines.pop();

  // re-assign it to the textarea
  $("#t").val(lines.join());

</script>
```

One thing you would need to check is that after the pop, you still have elements in the array to join.  I believe the array may be changed to a string if you pop an array with 2 or less items.

The above version does not take into account the carriage returns when putting it back together.  Try this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var s="";

  lines = $("#t").val().split("\n");

  // build a string with all elements, except the last
  for(i=0;i<lines.length-1;i++){ 
    s+=lines[i] + "\n"
  }

  // re-assign it to the textarea
  $("#t").val(s);

</script>
```

You will need to watch for lines at the end of the textarea which only contain a '\n'.

Comment: After the pop function, how would I format it so each entry is on its own line and not one string?

Comment: The first code example didn't take into account the carriage returns when putting the textarea back together.  I just updated it (see above).  Give that a spin.

Comment: It works but as soon as I click delete the add button stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out. Using .text(s) solved the problem. Thanks for your help keithlee - much appreciated!